# Given the mass density $\rho(x):=1/|x|$, a ball centered in the origin contains a finite amount of mass

Tags: mass, integration, geometry, density

Consider the following charge/mass distribution:
$$\mathbb{R}^3\ni x\mapsto\rho(x):=\frac{1}{|x|}$$

One can show that a ball centered in the origin contains a finite amount of charge/mass, i.e. that
$$\int_{B(0,r)}\rho<\infty$$
for all $r>0$ by using spherical coordinates. However, this seems counterintuitive to me, so I was wondering if there is some more enlightening explanation for this.

Comment: What is x? It is the radius in spherical coordinates?

Comment: @nasu $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $|x|$ is the distance from the origin.

Comment: I suppose the confusion comes from the different behavior depending on the dimension $D$: in $D = 1$, $\int_{-r}^{r}|x|^{-1}dx$ diverges, while for $D > 1$, $\int_{0}^{r} R^{-1} \cdot R^{D-1} dR \cdot \int d \Omega_D$ converges. One possible way of putting this in intuitive words may be by saying that higher dimensions means radially divergent densities have more directions to spread into, leading in this case to finite total charges as a net result.

Comment: @secavara Thank you for the comment. I didn't realize that this also works in two dimensions, where the situation can be visualized even better: I find it really surprising that the volume between the plane and the graph of$$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\ni x\mapsto \begin{cases}\frac{1}{|x|}&\text{if }0<|x|\leq 1\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}$$ is finite.

Comment: Related: Gabriel's Horn has a finite volume and an infinite surface area (https://math.jhu.edu/~brown/courses/s12/ExtraProblems/Section7.8Problem.pdf)

Comment: @hft Very nice, thank you!